# Jackson serialization - ignore not set values but provide values explicitly set to null

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, lombok

in my Spring Boot REST application I do want to achieve that properties of a class should be ignored by Jackson when they are not explicitly set. But if they are set to `null` they should be provided and serialized.

`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` ignores `null` values but makes no difference between actually unset values and values that have explicitly been set to `null`.

Check the following example (using Lombok) which shows what I want to achieve here:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Example {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty("test")
  private String test;
}
```

`Example.builder().test("test").build()` should result in `{test: "test"}`
`Example.builder().name(null).test("test).build()` should result in `{name: NULL, test: "test"}`

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using `Optional` fields:

```
public class JsonTest {
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    static class Example {
        private Optional<String> name;
        private Optional<String> test;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

        Example[] examples = {
                new Example(),
                Example.builder().name(Optional.of("exampleName")).build(),
                Example.builder().name(Optional.of("exampleName")).test(Optional.empty()).build(),
        };

        for (Example ex : examples) {
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(ex));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{}
{"name":"exampleName"}
{"name":"exampleName","test":null}
```

Comment: Yes, however, it works fine only for serialization :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, your attributes will be null when not set. So unless you add some sort of flag to know when an attribute has been actually set (even to null), you can not achieve what you want. That is, there is no difference between an unset attribute and an attribute set to null. If you did add a "isSet" flag (probably a map since its flag per attribute) then you would probably need a custom Jackson mapper that reads the "isSet" flags and acts accordingly.